# Genymotion path for Appium server

Tags: android, appium, genymotion

I am running automatic tests with Robot Framework on Android emulator and Appium server. The default Android Studio Emulator wasn't good enough, so I switched to Genymotion. But when now I run Appium server, I get this error:

> Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\build-tools'

I guess this is because Genymotion doesn't use Android SDK. Previously on this location there were emulator's virtual devices builds.

The question is: **what should be a proper path for Genymotion to work with Appium**? What's more when I change the default sdk path in Appium server's Android Settings, it is always "\build-tools" added at the end (which is not correct in that case). For example:

> error: Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\build-tools'

I don't know how to change it.
I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure

1. In Appium -

   ```
   Appium UI -> Android Settings -> Advanced
   SDK Path -> /User/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk  //this is just an example
   ```
2. In GenyMotion -

   ```
   Settings -> ADB -> Use GenyMotion Android tools (default)
                            OR
   Settings -> ADB -> Use custom sdk ->  /User/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk  // same as Appium
   ```